# Is it possible to merge two Google+ accounts?

Tags: google-plus, account-management

I have managed to get myself two Google+ accounts.

I created the first when it was in beta, but used a non Gmail address when signing up (I really can't remember why).

I can't add my existing Gmail account to my Google+ account - the only option is to start a new one.

I thought I'd try from the other direction (adding Google+ to my Gmail address) but all that did was create a new Google+ account.

So, now that I've got two Google+ accounts is it possible to merge them? I don't want to abandon the first (I have lots of people in my circles etc.) and while I don't use my Gmail account *that* much I'd rather not abandon that completely either.

Comment: Google, like Facebook and other online services, seems to have a big problem being helpful with accounts. Sure, they don't have the staff to deal with millions of accounts manually, but these large services are masters of automation; I'm sure they could work something out that would make the experience for users better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Account merge and data move options](https://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1109839)
, it's not possible:

> #### Merging Data
>
> Unfortunately, it is not possible to combine two accounts or to merge data.

However:

> #### Tool for moving data
>
> A [data moving tool](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=188096) is available for certain services if you’d like to transfer your data to your Google Apps account. However, the tool only is available for transferring data out of [conflicting accounts](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=181526).

Answer (score 4):

You can't merge your accounts
([link](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=63304)), but there is [migration tool](http://gigaom.com/2012/07/12/google-plus-apps-account-migration-tool/).

**EDIT**:

Also, you can transver it via [Google Takeout](https://google.com/takeout) ([see how to do that](http://lifehacker.com/5934343/how-can-i-migrate-my-google-data-from-one-account-to-another)).

I hope this helps you! :)

Comment: That's what I suspected but didn't want to hear.

Comment: Google does not allow merging accounts. :( I have also had a problem with transfering Google Places business listing, so I removed it from the first account and added it to the second one.